# How to update a button's text using Clock.schedule_interval in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am writing an app using kivy to check whether an USB device is connected or not without re-launching my app, As per the documentation I'm using Clock to call the required method for certain interval frequently. But, this always says the following error:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
import wmi

kv = """<KartScan@Screen>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    name: 'introscreen'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'index.png'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            size_hint: .5, .1
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            spacing: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y': .8}
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'left'
                size_hint_x: .5
                Button:
                    id: statebtn
                    size_hint: None, None
                    height: 50
                    width: self.texture_size[0]
                    padding: 10, 10
                    text: app.getusbdevices()"""

Builder.load_string(kv)
statebtn = Button(text="INSTRUMENT_NOT_FOUND")
class KartScan(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KartScan, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class KartScanApp(App):
    def build(self):
        k = KartScan()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.getusbdevices, 2)
        return k

    def getusbdevices(self):
        c = wmi.WMI()
        statebtn.text = u"INSTRUMENT_NOT_FOUND"
        wql = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"
        for item in c.query(wql):
            if "USB Device" in item.Dependent.Caption:
                statebtn.text = u"CONNECTED"
            else:
                statebtn.text = u"INSTRUMENT_NOT_FOUND"
        return statebtn.text
if __name__ == '__main__':
    KartScanApp().run()
```

Above is my Code: Can somebody help me to resolve this? 
This is the log i'm getting

> kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy_clock.c:7700) File "kivy_clock.pyx", line 397, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy_clock.c:7577) File "kivy_clock.pyx", line 395, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy_clock.c:7498) File "kivy_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick (kivy_clock.c:3490) TypeError: getusbdevices() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: This is th log i'm getting
   kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy\_clock.c:7700)
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 397, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy\_clock.c:7577)
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 395, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events (kivy\_clock.c:7498)
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 167, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick (kivy\_clock.c:3490)
 TypeError: getusbdevices() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method your pass to `Clock.schedule_interval` gets an additional parameter (that i usually call `dt` for delta-time), which express the amount of time elapsed since the scheduling or last call to the callback function. Here, you don't care about its value, but you still need to accept it.

change your method signature like this

```
class KartScanApp(App):
    […]

    def getusbdevices(self, dt):
        […]
```

and your code should work.